# ImproperOutputException in snakemake 5.5.4

Tags: snakemake

I am new to snakemake and recently I encountered a new error which I get only from very recent version of snakemake. This my snakemake rule

```
rule fastqc_raw:
    input:
        expand(directory("{fastqc_dir}/{samples}_fastqc/"),fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR, samples = SAMPLES_wo_extension)

rule do_fastqc_raw:
    input:
        expand("{fastq_dir}/{{samples}}.fastq.gz", fastq_dir =  inputDir)
    output:
        expand(directory("{fastqc_dir}/{{samples}}_fastqc/"),fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR)
    log:
        expand("{fastqc_dir}/{{samples}}.log", fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR)
    threads:
        10
    message:
        "performing fastQC of the sample : {wildcards.samples}"
    shell:
        """mkdir -p {output} && fastqc -q -t {threads} --outdir {output} --contaminants /home/Contaminants/idot.txt {input} 2> {log}"""
```

I get the following error which i didn't receive when I use snakemake version lower than 5.2.0

> ImproperOutputException in line 10 of /home/FASTQC.snakefile:
>   Outputs of incorrect type (directories when expecting files or vice versa). Output directories must be flagged with directory(). for rule do_fastqc_raw:

Comment: What happens if you switch the expand and directory in the output line?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Oops I just noticed that my answer may be the same as your comment. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Doesn't matter, we're here to help :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have `directory` in the wrong place in rule `do_fastqc_raw`.

This:

```
output:
    expand(directory("{fastqc_dir}/{{samples}}_fastqc/"),fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR)
```

should be:

```
output:
    directory(expand("{fastqc_dir}/{{samples}}_fastqc/", fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR))
```

Comment: Can you show the line you have edited? Are you sure you have put the parethesis in the right places?

Comment: Like you suggested I changed the order like following                                                     directory(expand("{fastqc_dir}/{{samples}}_fastqc/", fastqc_dir = FASTQC_DIR)), The I get the following error "No values given for wildcard 'fastqc_dir'" although I declared the fastqc_dir.

Comment: But when I changed the the output  rule like following "directory(expand("{{fastqc_dir}}/{{samples}}_fastqc/")", then the error disappeared.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with your last error, but you should probably swap `expand` and `directory` also in rule `fastqc_raw`